# Doubling the size of an icon in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons, resize, size

In Flutter want an icon that's a fixed factor larger than "usual", for example 2X size. I see the `size` parameter in the Icon constructor, and according to the doc for this parameter, the size "Defaults to the nearest `IconTheme`'s `IconThemeData.size`." But when I attempt to fetch this default using

`Theme.of(context).iconTheme.size`

that expression returns null. But Icons can be created in the context and they do have *some* normal size. So how do I determine the normal size? How do set the `size` of an icon to be two-times the size it normally would be by default?

I'm aware of `Transform()` and that would probably work. But I'm still wondering how to set the size parameter of `Icon()` based on something concrete.

Comment: I tried Transform. It does scale the size of the icon, but for some reason the layout bounding box doesn't scale and the layout is wonky.

Answer (score 1):

If no theme is specified it uses a fallback

```
  const IconThemeData.fallback() 
       : size = 24.0, 
         fill = 0.0, 
         weight = 400.0, 
         grade = 0.0, 
         opticalSize = 48.0, 
         color = const Color(0xFF000000), 
         _opacity = 1.0, 
         shadows = null;
```

[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_theme_data.dart&ved=2ahUKEwjh_ojkscj_AhUu-DgGHWC_CCgQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3BRZ22qjZeqYz9AytXG6-k)

You can use

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 1.0,//scalevalue here
  child: Icon(Icons.home),
),
```

Comment: LOL, so are you saying there's a "default default default?"  How do I access this 'fallback'? Where is it?

Comment: I could do ```var defaultIconTheme = IconThemeData();
    var defaultSize = defaultIconTheme.size;```  to figure out what this default is, but how do I know that this is the size that the framework uses?  Is it guaranteed these will match when ```Theme.of(context).iconTheme.size == null``?

Comment: Whoops! ```defaultSize = defaultIconTheme.size``` also returns null.

Answer (score 0):

improving @furkanages's solution u can have constant values for enum fields in dart by using this it would be like that.

```dart
enum IconSize {
  small(16),
  medium(24),
  large(32);

  final double value;
  const IconSize(this.value);
}

class MyIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final IconSize size;

  const MyIcon({super.key, required this.icon, this.size = IconSize.medium});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(
      icon,
      size: size.value,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The point of my question wasn't to ask how to set the size of an icon, or how to multiply by 2, or how to create my own resizable icon. These answers miss the point. Rather, my question was how to scale the size of a standard icon provided by the framework.

Comment: Oh its seem i misunderstood. U can use Transform.scale then @ChrisNadovich

Comment: Yeah, Transform doesn't quite work -- it changes the size of the icon but screws up the layout, wheras using size: works perfectly, but how to set size: ????

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Enums like below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum IconSize { small, medium, large }

class MyIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final IconSize size;

  const MyIcon({required this.icon, this.size = IconSize.medium});

  double getSizeValue(IconSize size) {
    switch (size) {
      case IconSize.small:
        return 16.0;
      case IconSize.medium:
        return 24.0;
      case IconSize.large:
        return 32.0;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double iconSize = getSizeValue(size);

    return Icon(
      icon,
      size: iconSize,
    );
  }
}

 MyIcon(
icon: Icons.abc,
 size: IconSize.medium,
),
```

Comment: This answer misses the point. In a material app, I can create an icon with Icon(Icons.whatever). It come out at a certain size. There's a size parameter for Icon() to set the size, but I don't know what it is initially so I don't know how to change the size in proportion to this initial unknown value. Get it?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a custom theme?

`MaterialApp` by default uses the theme `ThemeData().light` where `iconTheme.size = 24` by default.

If `Theme.of(context).iconTheme.size` is `returning null`, that might be because you're using a custom theme and did not specify the iconTheme.size. I also recommend using the .copyWith to avoid any undefined theme.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: customTheme,
),

final customTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    size: 24.0,
  ),
);
```

Please note that the above icon size is applied to all Icons in Material widgets only.

If you want to set the default size for icons in a Scaffold's appbar for example, you have to define the actionIconTheme:

```
actionIconTheme: ActionIconThemeData(
    backButtonIconBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded, size: 24);
    },
    closeButtonIconBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Icon(Icons.close, size: 24);
    },
    drawerButtonIconBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Icon(Icons.menu, size: 24);
    },
    endDrawerButtonIconBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined, size: 24);
    },
  ),
```

or if you want to set the default size for icons in a Scaffold's bottomNavigationBar, you have to define the bottomNavigationBarTheme:

```
bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
  unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 24),);
  selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 24),);
```

There are plenty more to look out for. I suggest using your IDE's tools to list all available parameters and explore.

Comment: I'm not using a custom theme.